# ויהיה ערב ויהיה בוקר - what's the nature of those emergences?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, creation

> "וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים  לָאוֹר יוֹם וְלַחֹשֶׁךְ קָרָא לָיְלָה **וַיְהִי**־עֶרֶב **וַיְהִי**־בֹקֶר יוֹם אֶחָד׃"
> "God called the light Day, and the darkness He called Night.
> And there **was** evening and there **was** morning, one day." [Gen.1.5](http://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

Previously, the earth **"was"** (ibid 2) after God explicitly created it, and God uttered/commanded/created the light **to be**, saying "let there **be (יהי)** light". But here God didn't do anything, it is just mentioned that the evening and the morning **were**.

What kind of emergence is it? If God didn't create them, where did they come from? Was it a natural process of mixing *the* light with (already introduced) darkness?

Comment: What do you mean by emergence?

Comment: The verse is saying that G-d set a time limit for the day and night (see Rashi) and that time had passed.

Comment: @N.T. How did the time pass?

Comment: Ramban says Hashem also created time.